# Groovy to validate if Node exists or not

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to validate in Groovy if a node came from an external system, if the external system has a value the node comes with a value, if the system don't have a value the node doesn't come in the payload.

Based on this I need to change/correct if its a NEW or UPDATE process for that record in an existing node.

Incoming XML is:

```
    <urn:ExternalReqForApprovalImportRequest xmlns:urn="urn:Ariba:Buyer:vrealm_1" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" partition="" variant="">
        <urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item>
            <urn:item>
                <urn:Name>TEST</urn:Name>
                <urn:Operation>XXXXXX</urn:Operation>
                <urn:HeaderExtrinsics>
                    <Extrinsics>
                        <Extrinsic name="PRRefID">THIS IS THE NODE THAT MAY OR NOT MAY COME</Extrinsic>
                        <Extrinsic name="XXXXXXX">Value</Extrinsic>
                        <Extrinsic name="AnotherField">TValue</Extrinsic>
                    </Extrinsics>
                </urn:HeaderExtrinsics>
            </urn:item>
        </urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item>
    </urn:ExternalReqForApprovalImportRequest>
```

I created this groovy:

```
    import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.lang.String;
    
    def Message processData(Message message) {
        
        map = message.getProperties();
           value = map.get("PRRefID");
    
     Reader reader = message.getBody(Reader)
    
     def FG = new XmlParser().parse(reader)
        
    if(value == null) {
 FG.'urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item'.'urn:item'.'urn:HeaderExtrinsics'.Operation = "NEW"

    } else {
      FG.'urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item'.'urn:item'.'urn:HeaderExtrinsics'.Operation = "UPDATE"
    }
    
        message.setBody(FG);
        
        return message;
    }
```

What I want to achieve is validate if Extrinsic with name PRRefID comes in the XML, if it comes I need to update the **Operation** to UPDATE, if it doesn't come I need to set NEW as the value.

I tried to map the xpath as a Property (probably there is a cleaner way to map this from the direct xpath), but my issue right now is changing the value, since it's a extrinsic with a specific name, apparently that is nor the right format for the assignation, so which should it be?

Thank you.

Comment: FG.ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item....

Answer (score 0):

Just needs some syntax tweaks,

```
FG.'urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item'.'urn:item'.'urn:HeaderExtrinsics'.Extrinsics.Extrinsic[0].value = "NEW"
```

You have to specify the namespace wherever necessary

Note that when you parse, `FG` becomes root of the document so don't specify `urn:ExternalReqForApprovalImportRequest` again

I assumed you are trying to update the text node value

Note also that `Extrinsic` will be an array of nodes, so you have to refer to it by index

Comment: I had to edit the question, i didnt formulate ok, the value i need to change is OPERATION based on the value of the property PRRefID(or direct XPATH for PRRefID), validation for the property i believe is ok, i changed the assignation according to your recommendation to the right OPERATION field but still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it following your recommendation in the namespace!

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.lang.String;
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def Message processData(Message message) {
    
    map = message.getProperties();
    value = map.get("PRRefID");

    Reader reader = message.getBody(Reader)
    def root = new XmlParser().parse(reader)

if(value == "") {
    root.'urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item'.'urn:item'.'urn:Operation'[0].value = "NEW"
}
    message.setBody(XmlUtil.serialize(root))
    return message;
}
```

Thank you.